# Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork проверка на больше 0

Tags: tfs

Через конструктор форм в VisualStudio открываю форму Задачи.
    Хочу, чтобы поле "Завершенная работа" 
    (**Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.CompletedWork**) становилась READONLY, когда 
    "Оставшаяся работа" (Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork) < 0

```
Добавляю для "Завершенной работы" Правило "WHEN", указываю Field: 
Microsoft.VSTS.Scheduling.RemainingWork а в поле Value ничего не могу 
указать.
Студия требует конкретного значения. Там нельзя взять и написать ">0"

Подскажите, возможно ли в поле Value добавить условие? Чтобы была проверка на больше 0 ?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Не умеет он сравнивать на больше или меньше, только на соответствие конкретному значению, в данном случае 0. В принципе, если пользователь поставил 0 для оставшейся работы, то этого уже может быть достаточно. Какой смысл указывать меньше нуля?

Можно также пойти другим путем - завязать проверку на состояние. Если задача закрыта, то нельзя обновлять поля. А пока открыта, пусть заполняются насколько необходимо.

Comment: Здравствуйте.
Спасибо за ответ. Странно конечно, что нельзя сравнивать на больше или меньше. Но видимо M$ это сделано специально. Можно было наверно заморочиться за плагин, и юзать событие OnChange поля, но в моём случае оно того не стОит.